# Formating the json data in php

Tags: php, json

I have the json data in following format

```
["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","5","4","3","0"]
```

I want to convert the above data in to following format using php

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,5,4,3,0]
```

How can i do this using php

Thanks

Comment: What output do you want ? A string, an array ?

Comment: Actually initially i had an array in php after that i have converted the array in to json using json_encode function after that it returns an string containing the JSON representation of value as following   ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","5","4","3","0"], Now i want same string but values should not enclosed by double comma ("")

Comment: Your problem is that those items in the array are considered strings in your php... you can fix it with the array_map('intval', array()) example in my answer. When things are considered strings in PHP, the json_encode() method adds the double quotes around the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_map to typecast all items in the array to an integer with the callback intval.

For integers in an array:

```
$array = array_map('intval', json_decode('["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","5","4","3","0"]'));
```

Retrieve JSON from array:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: @salloy If it completely answered your question, please mark my answer as the answer to your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","2","5","4","3","0"]';
echo str_replace('"','', $string);
```

Output is:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,5,4,3,0]
```